# More efficient way to get strings out of a Dart list of classes

Tags: dart

Just looking for a more efficient way to do this in Dart:

```
List<String> tagStrings = List();
List<TagCategory> categories = List();
    source.forEach(
      (content) {
        if (content.tagCategories != null) {
          categories.addAll(content.tagCategories);
        }
      },
    );
    categories = categories.toSet().toList(); // remove duplicates
    categories.forEach(
      (element) {
        List<Tag> tags = element.tags;
        tags.forEach(
          (tag) {
            tagStrings.add(tag.label);
          },
        );
      },
    );
    tagStrings = tagStrings.toSet().toList();
```

I have a list of `Trail` objects with a list of `TagCategory` objects that themselves have a list of `Tag` objects with a `String` property called `label`.

I am trying to strip out all these tags for use in a filter, and I need duplicates to be removed hence the hack to convert to a `set` and then back into a list which I can sort.

What is the most efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Converting to a set to avoid duplicates is fine.

I'd write it as a literal:
Try:

```dart
var tags = [...{for (var tag in {for (var content in source) ...?content.tagCategories})
                  tag.label}];
```

You can then worry about whether you really need to remove duplicates in tag categories if you are removing the duplicates in the labels afterwards anyway.

If performance is the only goal, then I'd probably do something slightly more imperative, like:

```dart
var set = <String>{}
for (var content in source) {
  var categories = content.tagCategories;
  if (categories != null) {
    for (var category in categories) set.add(category.label);
  }
}
var tagStrings = set.toList();
```